# Can't get attributes of an xml element properly

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone

I'm trying to get the attributes value of this yahoo weather XML element:

```
<yweather:wind chill="24" direction="340" speed="28.97" />
```

like this:

```
XDocument XResult = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

XElement location = XResult.Elements(XName.Get("wind", "yweather")).FirstOrDefault();

XAttribute city = location.Attributes(XName.Get("chill")).FirstOrDefault();
XAttribute direction = location.Attributes(XName.Get("direction")).FirstOrDefault();
XAttribute speed = location.Attributes(XName.Get("speed")).FirstOrDefault();
```

but it tells me object not set to an instance. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the entire XML document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the namespace uri instead of namespace name, for example :

```
XElement location = XResult.Elements(XName.Get("wind", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"))
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

if the element is direct child of root node, this simplified one should work as well :

```
XElement location = XResult.Element(XName.Get("wind", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"));
```

otherwise you need to use `Descendants()` instead of `Elements()` :

```
XElement location = XResult.Descendants(XName.Get("wind", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"))
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its like this

```
XDocument XResult = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

XElement location = XResult.Descendants(XName.Get("wind", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0")).FirstOrDefault();

XAttribute city = location.Attributes(XName.Get("chill")).FirstOrDefault();
XAttribute direction = location.Attributes(XName.Get("direction")).FirstOrDefault();
XAttribute speed = location.Attributes(XName.Get("speed")).FirstOrDefault();
```